# Prepping new, very rough, pressure-treated pine fence for staining

Tags: sanding, pressure-treated, fence

Our new 6' privacy fence is very rough, shaggy, almost furry. We've been told it's best to get the surface smooth before staining both to allow for better absorption and to prevent unevenness when the shag wears/falls off.

Sanding with 36-grit belt sander gummed up the belt quickly so we switched to a power hand planer, then sanding. This is taking forever. Removing the pickets for treatment is not an option. Does anyone have a better idea?

The fence is just off the sidewalk and very visible so we want it to look nice and to be easy to maintain over the years so I'd rather do the hard work on the front end, just wish it wasn't so hard.

I've little experience with wood so any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a picture of how furry this is?  I'm guessing this thing must be quite shaggy looking if it gummed up the belt sander.  At any rate, seeing what you are dealing with might make it easier to recommend something.

Comment: I've read it can be the pine resin heating up from the sanding which makes sense. After being planed the sandpaper lasts much longer, not sure why. The trouble is my lack of skill with the planer leaves marks which take a long time to sand out. After 100 grit it looks great but it's taken over a week to do 40 feet and I've got 100 to go. Not to mention the inside...

Comment: You didn't have to do anything to these really if you're willing to keep up with maintenance, in my part of the world fencing is often shaggy like this, and used as-is. Apologies for how this sounds but if a smoother finish was what was desired the boards should have been addressed before installation, or smoother boards bought initially. Smoothing in situ is possible, but backbreaking work, as you know all too well already. And unfortunately, you're already doing it pretty much the only way that makes sense so I don't think there's much we can provide other than our commiserations, sorry.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. Graphus, you are correct on all counts. In my area we have a mix of nicely stained, sloppily stained, gorgeous cedar and untreated/greyed and left to rot. We could have applied the product as-is but after testing it on raw and sanded wood we much preferred the sanded. We were assured 'a quick sanding' for prep would suffice so we let it go. Oh well.

Comment: Got timed out on edit...Had we known how it would turn out we'd have done a lot different. Cabot reps and others have said it's much better to get it smooth now than fuss with it later and I agree. My goal here was to find out if there was anything I should be doing differently and you've answered that, so thank you. I wouldn't buy this fence again, but I'm not sorry for doing the work, it looks so much better, just want to do it the least painful way ;) all the stain people I've asked said down the road I'll be glad so here's hoping. Thanks again for helping.

Comment: A solid colour stain might be your best option as it will work over rough wood

Comment: Monte, yes, it would. We've chosen a light transparent stain thus the prep work. It's a long expanse and we felt a solid stain would make it too monolithic. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Glad you're not too disheartened, and sorry again there's no real help we can provide. BTW, presume you're wearing a (good) dust mask when doing the planing and sanding? Even working outdoors it is important to protect yourself from the dust from pressure-treated wood, raw wood not so much.

Comment: Graphus, yes, I've got a good mask and wear form-fitting glasses for the plane step. It does make a mess, the area looks like it's covered with shredded coconut. Your response did help-I didn't want to get to the end and learn of a great time and labor saving tool or technique after the fact (facepalm!). I'm consoling myself that a fence of pre-dried and planed wood would have been twice the cost. After this bit of fun I need to find a way to cover the gaps created by the pickets shrinking. If nothing else, it keeps me out of trouble for a while. Thanks again.

Comment: Just in case anyone sees this and is having similar troubles with pine clogging up sandpaper-spray it with Pam. I'm not making this up. I read it on another forum about pine flooring. He suggested spraying the sandpaper with Pam (or any oil in a spray bottle) and it would keep it clean. He  posted photos of two drums, one treated and one not. treated was clear, other was caked. I've done 10-12 boards with no gumming-before, 1 1/2 boards ruined it. The rough comes off fast and no gouges from the planer. This will be so much faster. So, if it happens to you try Pam. Hope this helps someone.